# Mongo: document find on date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Here its my mongodb database structure

```
coordinates : {
    lat : {type: Number},
    lon : {type: Number},

},
timeStamp :{type: Date} ,
accuracy :{type: Number},
deviceId : {type: Number},
deviceType : {type: String},
simId : {type: String}
```

I want to find document on date.

here its my query for getting document from mongodb

```
db.LocationInfoCollection.find({"deviceId":911441051085656,"timeStamp":{$gte:new Date("2015-09-07T12:56:44.000Z")}})
```

when I'm run above query on mongodb return blank array.

Above query perfectly run on mongo shell. But not in my code.

output on mongo shell

```
  {

    "timeStamp": "2015-09-08T12:31:24.000Z",
    "accuracy": 5,
    "deviceId": 911441051085656,
    "simId": "123456",
    "_id": "55eed361dfa115387dade3ce",
    "coordinates": {
      "lat": 20.998,
      "lon": 75.5667
    }
  }
```

How can I get document on above date query.

Comment: You have stored "timestamp" as "String" DataType. Try below query :    db.LocationInfoCollection.find({"deviceId":911441051085656,"timeStamp":{$gte:"2015-09-07T12:56:44.000Z"}});

Comment: @YathishManjunath I would not be so sure of that as `_id` is also listed in this "dump" as a "string". But it may be. Which is why the general ask is to please show the mongodb "shell" output in the question, so it is clear what the field "types" are. But likely the case if the `Date` casting does not match. Please add `.findOne()` output from the shell to make things clear. Oh and NIKHIL, the "schema" is not of consequence here if the "data" does not in fact match the schema. Please show the document. Also show the "code", as that is where your problem is.

Comment: That's output from your "node" application running mongoose. Try again. Copy/Paste.

Comment: your query is running on mongo shell perfectly. where the problem is ? i mean on which plateform / language you are running

Comment: @ Hitesh Mundra I'm using nodejs with mongoose

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add your server code here so we hav emore of understanding of your broken code, here is something from your server.js you might be talking about:

```
var app = require('express');
var Coordinate = require('/models/coordinate.js');
app.get('/api/coordinates/:id', function (req, res) {
    var targetId = req.params.id;
    Coordinate.findOne({_id: targetId}, function (err, review) {
        coordinates.date
        res.json(coordinates);
    })
});
```

Let me know if this helps!